# How do I remove a Git repository and settings and rebuild it from scratch in Linux?

Tags: git

I set up a remote git repository on github, and set up a remote connection on my linux terminal. But I got the folder system wrong. So I deleted the repository from github and wanted to start from the beginning again.
But now there's old credentials that I can't seem to change, and everything I'm finding online only gets to the part where you clone the repository to your system.
Is there a way to do a clean sweep of my git settings? And is there a place that walks you through not just setting up a connection, but defining the main branch?

Comment: What setting did you want to change? (Also the global settings for git are probably stored in `~/.gitconfig` and you can delete that if you want to reset everything)

Comment: @AlectoIrenePerez I was wanting to change/set up the main branch properly.

Comment: Are you trying to use `main` as the default?

Comment: Yes. But I keep on getting an error when I want to push

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the default branch to main, use `git config`:

```sh
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

This will not rename any branches in any existing repositories, and it will only apply to new repositories.

To rename a branch in an existing repository, use `git branch --move` on the branch you want to rename. For example, to rename a branch named master, checkout that branch, and then use `git branch --move`:

```sh
git checkout master
git branch --move main
```